# Cannot authenticate to mongodb stitch app with google oauth

Tags: vuejs2, google-oauth, mongodb-stitch

I'm working in a vue.js frontend. I can successfully make calls to stitch and write to the database if I use anonymous authentication. When I switch to Google oauth and attempt to make the same write call to the database I get the following error:

```
uncaught exception: t: (MustAuthenticateFirst): method called requires being authenticated
```

I've setup the Google Authentication Provider in the Stitch Admin console. I've created and configured a project on the Google Cloud Platform. In my vue code I've added a "login with google" button that runs this snippet:

```
  loginWithGoogle() {
    const googleCredential = new GoogleRedirectCredential();
    client.auth.loginWithRedirect(googleCredential);
  },
```

When I click to login I'm redirected to a Google form and asked to login by Google, then successfully redirected back to my app. But when I then try to write to stitch database it still says that I must authenticate first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you call de hasRedirectResult() and  handleRedirectResult() when google redirect back to your app?. This method store credential locally (I guest in localstorage).

Comment: Perfect. Adding those 2 methods in a method called by the vue created lifecycle hooked made everything work as expected.